# OnScrollListener não funciona OnItemClickListener

Tags: android

OnItemClickListener não funciona ao clicar em um cliente da pesquisa.

Olá. Tenho uma tela que é uma ListActivity, quando abro, ela traz os cliente perfeitamente do banco, funcionando o OnScrollListener e também OnItemClickListener.

No entanto na mesma tela tem um edittext para pesquisa; então quando faço a pesquisa, traz o cliente normal, o problema é que o OnItemClickListener não funciona ao clicar em um cliente da pesquisa.

```js
public class Lista_Clientes extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener, OnScrollListener {
...
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    preencherclientes
    getListView().setOnScrollListener(this);
    }

//Esse método está funcionando normal ao clicar em cliente que não tiver sido pesquisado
//No entanto ao pesquisar ele não funciona mais.
 @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l,View v,int position,long id){

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);                

        Cliente cliente = (Cliente) this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);

        if (RetornaResultado) { 
            adicionaResultado(String.valueOf(cliente.getIDcli()));
        } else {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Act_ConsultaCliente.class);
            Act_ConsultaCliente.mCodCliente = String.valueOf(cliente.getIDcli());
            startActivity(i);
        }        

    }

public void preencherclientes(int mais, boolean usaFiltro) {

        String limite = " LIMIT 20 OFFSET "+mais+"";
        //String sAux = "";
        if (!(mSpoApp.getManager().getConfiguracaoAparelhoVendedor(1) == null))
            sAux = " and _id in (select idcli from clienterotavendedor where idrot = (select rota_id from configuracaoaparelhovendedor))";

        if (!usaFiltro) { 
            listCliente.addAll(mSpoApp
                    .getManager()
                    .getClienteDao()
                    .getAllbyClause("1=1 "+sAux+" order by nome "+limite,null,null, null,null));    
        } else {
            listCliente = mSpoApp.getManager().getClienteDao().getAllbyClause("1 = 1 " + sAux + 
                            " and nome like '%" + mEdtFiltro.getText().toString() + "%' " +
                            "or (fantasia like '%" + mEdtFiltro.getText().toString()+"%') " +
                            "or (cpf like '%" + mEdtFiltro.getText().toString()+"%') " +
                            "or (cnpj like '%" + mEdtFiltro.getText().toString()+"%') " +
                            "or (_id = '" + mEdtFiltro.getText().toString() + "') order by nome " + limite,null,null, null,null);            
        }


        mClientesAdapter = new Adapter_ListaClientes(Lista_Clientes.this, listCliente);


        setListAdapter(mClientesAdapter);

    }   

    public void adicionarclientes(int mais) {
        String limite = " LIMIT 20 OFFSET "+mais+"";
        String sAux = "";
        if (!(mSpoApp.getManager().getConfiguracaoAparelhoVendedor(1) == null))
            sAux = " and _id in (select idcli from clienterotavendedor where idrot = (select rota_id from configuracaoaparelhovendedor))";

        listCliente.addAll(mSpoApp
                .getManager()
                .getClienteDao()
                .getAllbyClause("1=1 "+sAux+" order by nome "+limite,null,null, null,null));    
        mClientesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

@Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int primeiroItemVisivel,
            int quantidadeDeItensVisiveis, int totalDeItensNoAdapter) {
        if(primeiroItemVisivel + quantidadeDeItensVisiveis >= totalDeItensNoAdapter - 0) {

                adicionarclientes(totalDeItensNoAdapter);

        }
    }

@Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        //

    }
```

Comment: O método não é executado ou é executado de forma errada?

Comment: Ele não é executado quando é feito a pesquisa, no entanto se eu clicar e arrastar ele mostra todos os outros cliente e abre o cliente desejado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver meu problema.
O problema estava, que, quando eu  fazia a busca ele tentava adicionar novamente na lista, porque a lista logo chegava ao final porque o último item da lista era visível

```js
 @Override
 public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int primeiroItemVisivel,
   int quantidadeDeItensVisiveis, int totalDeItensNoAdapter) {
  if(primeiroItemVisivel + quantidadeDeItensVisiveis >= totalDeItensNoAdapter - 0) {
   /**
    * Aqui faço o tratamento para aumetar a lista
    * Como preciso adicionar na lista somente enquanto tiver dados no banco
    * fiz o if para verificar se ja chegou no final
    * se chegar não adicione mais na lista
    */
   
   //Se total de itens no adapter não for maior ou igual a 20, não faça nada 
   if (totalDeItensNoAdapter >=20) {
    
   
    //Se total for diferente do total de itens que tem no adapter
    //Contar recebe o valor total de itens no adapter
    //Quando total for igual o número de itens no adapter, então total recebe um amais
    if (total != totalDeItensNoAdapter) {
     total = totalDeItensNoAdapter;
    } else {
     total++; 
    }
    
    //Se a soma de primeito intem visível + quantidade de itens visível for igual 
    if ((primeiroItemVisivel + quantidadeDeItensVisiveis) == totalDeItensNoAdapter) {
     //Enquanto total não for maior que total de itens no adapter, adicione novos clientes
     if (!(total>totalDeItensNoAdapter)) {
      adicionarclientes(totalDeItensNoAdapter);
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
```